# Laravel 7 make relation to found out who invited me

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

in my web application each can be have unlimited user like with networking system. i can found which user registered with user ref code, but i want to know who is my parent and invited me to register

for example this code can be return how many user registered with my ref code:

```
$users = User::whereNull('user_id')->with('child')->get();
```

model:

```
public function child()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class)->with('child');
}
```

how can i found out who is parent of child? like with from tree branch to root

`User` migration file:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->string('name')->nullable();
    $table->string('family')->nullable();
    $table->string('username')->unique();

    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->index()->nullable();

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

    $table->string('password');

    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
});
```

`User` model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime'
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class)->with('users');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the parents

```
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

To get the childs

```
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution work fine:

```
public function child()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class)->with('child');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```